# Opentext REST API Creating Binders

Tags: rest, api, opentext

I am looking to utilize opentext REST API to create binder.

[image]

I have looked into their documentation: 
https://developer.opentext.com/webaccess/#url=%2Fawd%2Fresources%2Fapis%2Fcontent-server-v1%23!%2Fnodes&tab=501

It appears that I have to POST the type, parent_id and name. Type for binders is 
31066 .

[image]

When I post request I get 400 BAD REQUEST. I have posted this to opentext forum as well :

https://developer.opentext.com/webaccess/#url=%2Fawd%2Fforums%2Fquestions%2F18889322&tab=501

Looking for any suggestions/pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used OpenText WebService to Create Binders. WebService Provides a Copy Method.

I created a Master Template and used the Copy method to create a copy and then updated all metadata.